# d3js - choropleth csv file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js, csv

I am working with crime data from the entire nation.  I wish to display the data in a choropleth, a la [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606)!

My question is, suppose I wanted to compare the choropleth of this crime data with a choropleth of a different dimension, say petition signature data.  Could I just include the magnitude for the petition signature data in the same tsv or csv file as the crime data?  It looks like the code from the example is indifferent to how many columns the referenced tsv has.  See this:

```
queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "assets/counties.json")
  .defer(d3.csv, "assets/crime.csv", function(d) { rateById.set(d.id, +d.magnitude);
    data[d.id] = d.magnitude;
    })
  .await(ready);
```

Thanks!  Just looking to DRY my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just include more data. As long as you keep the existing columns with their names and everything you add has a different name, the existing code should work fine.